# The identity 'xyz@demo.com' for field 'Assigned To' is not in scope of this organization. Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

When I tried to assign a task in Azure DevOps, I received the following error message

> The identity '' for field 'Assigned To' is not in scope of this organization. Azure devops

How do I fix this?

Comment: is your devops organisation configured with "demo.com" domain ?

Comment: https://dev.azure.com/xyzdevops/ is the organization url

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar You can't use a fake account like `xyz@demo.com`, because `xyz@demo.com` isn't a part of your Azure Active Directory tenant. Or at least, I'm guessing it isn't because you probably don't own `demo.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity 'xyz@demo.com' is not added as a user in the Azure devops project

Answer (score 0):

Tested on my side, I could reproduce your error message in Azure DevOps.

[image]

I have created this user in my organization linked Azure AD, but not added this account into Azure DevOps as user.

[image]

In common, adding this user (xyz@demo.com) to Azure DevOps organization as a valid user could resolve your issue.